# Proving a pair isn't in a relation?

Tags: lean

I'm doing a homework problem and I'm not sure how to approach it. Basically I have to prove that two numbers share a relationship of being successors, and it was easy to prove that (2, 3) has this relationship. But how can I prove that (2, 4) does not? Here's my code so far.

```
inductive succ_rel : Nat → Nat → Prop
    | pair (a : Nat) : succ_rel a (Nat.succ a)

open succ_relation

example : succ_rel 2 3 := pair 2
```

--Not sure how to prove (2, 4) does not belong here

Answer (score 1):

Use [`nomatch`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Parser/Term.html#Lean.Parser.Term.nomatch) to prove that `¬succ_rel 2 4`:

```
inductive succ_rel : Nat → Nat → Prop
  | pair (a : Nat) : succ_rel a (Nat.succ a)

example :  succ_rel 2 3 := succ_rel.pair 2
example : ¬succ_rel 2 4 := fun h ↦ nomatch h
```

You can also define the binary relation of one natural number being the successor of another as follows:

```
def Nat.isSuccOf (n m : Nat) : Prop := n = m.succ

example :  Nat.isSuccOf 3 2 := rfl
example : ¬Nat.isSuccOf 4 2 := fun h ↦ nomatch h
example : ¬Nat.isSuccOf 4 2 := by simp [Nat.isSuccOf]
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**